# how to use or condition in html with pipe

Tags: html, pipe

I want to display NA if no variable value is there in html. 
I either get 0 or $0.00 || "N/A" using these:

```
  <span class="summary-label">Fee Amount:</span>
                <span>{{(account.feeAmount | currency) || ("N/A")}}</span>
              </div>

 <span class="summary-label">Amount Held:</span>
                <span>{{account.amountHeld | currency }} || "N/A"</span>
              </div>
```

Any idea?

Comment: What templating language are you using? Is that VUE?

Comment: this is in html .. backend its angular/typescript

Comment: HTML has no conditionals built in. You have to use the built Angular conditionals to achieve what you are looking for. Im not familiar with Angular but a google search for Angular HTML conditionals got me here - https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf